# Generate Html table from Javascript using API (The moviedb.org)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I am using themoviedb.org api to print images and information from their database. Now i want to format the images description and rating to appear nicely into table rows (like the images shown in the link.  What is the best practice to generate Html from js-jquery?
In the link you can see, the user searches for the movie and they appear below. See an example here: https://wherehd.herokuapp.com/

Also when the user searches again for another movie i want to delete the previous results and replace with the new ones.

Here is how my js code looks like:

```
   function search()
    {



        var movieTitle = $('#search_field').val();
        var str1 = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?include_adult=false&page=1&query=";
        var str2 = "&language=en-US&api_key=xxx";
        var searchResult = str1+movieTitle+str2;


        //var searchResult = str1.concat(encodeURI(movieTitle)).concat(str2);

        var settings = 
        {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": searchResult,
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {},
            "data": "{}"

        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);

            var results = response.results;

        for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++)
        {

            var movie = results[i];
            var description = movie.overview;
            var title = movie.title;
            var image = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + movie.poster_path;
            var releaseDate = movie.release_date;
            //Display the description and image

            if(movie.poster_path != null )
            {
                /*$("#Search-Results").append('<br><h1 style="color:red;font-size:32px;">'+title+'</h1>: '+description+'<br> Release date: <b style="color:yellow;">'+releaseDate+'</b><br> <img style="width:200px;height:300px;" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500'+movie.poster_path+'"/>');*/

 $("#Search-Results").append('<br><h1 style="color:red;font-size:32px;">'
+title+'</h1> '+description+'<br> Release date: <b style="color:yellow;">
'+releaseDate+'</b><br> <img style="width:155px;height:214px;" 
src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500'+movie.poster_path+'"/>');
            }



        }


    });

    }
```

Comment: So where is the code that generates your table?

Comment: So call empty() on the element you are appending the data too.

Comment: it is at the end where i get the element by the id search-results and i append the information with some html. I didn't create any table yet. But it's a mess there it is difficult and it becomes a mess to create tables there

Comment: @epascarello do i need to create another function?

Comment: If you really want to generate a table, give us some sample JSON and a sample output, and well do that...

Comment: @Jonasw go to the link and find everything in the console. Btw why do you need json? I use jquery

Comment: @csandreas1 why should i? Its not my job to dig through your code its yours to present... That has nothing todo with jquery, ive just meant giving a sample response...

Comment: @Jonasw well that has only to do with jquery and html. My case is to generate the html through js file into a nice format with tr and td.

Comment: @csandreas1 i know. Looks like you dont know JSON...

Comment: I would love to learn json if this would be a better practise with less error prompts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a table from some JS objects you might want to take a look at Datatables plugin (it's pretty easy to use, has lots of features):
https://datatables.net/

Comment: i want to create table so that the movies will appear nicely next to each other. I don't want to create so complicated tables.